# Seems that some object reference keep in memory?

Tags: jquery

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/pfnw9/1/) :

## HTML

```
<a id="go" href="javascript:void(0);">Start</a>

<div id="container">
    <div class="example" id="example1">1</div>
    <div class="example" id="example2">2</div>
    <div class="example" id="example3">3</div>
</div>
```

## jQuery

```
$('#go').click(function () {
    InitDragDrop();
});

function InitDragDrop() {
    var BoxImmagineFutura = null;
    
    $('#boxTemp').remove();
    BoxImmagineFutura = $('<div/>', { id: 'boxTemp', class: 'boxTempClass', text: 'Added' });
    BoxImmagineFutura.appendTo($("#container"));
    
    $('.example').mousedown(function (e) {
        BoxImmagineFutura.insertBefore("#example2");
        BoxImmagineFutura.show();
    });
}
```

## CSS

```
.example, #boxTemp
{
    float:left;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#boxTemp
{
    background-color:red;
    display:none;
}
​
```

In order :

1. Click Start to initialize function/handlers;
2. Click on a div (you will show the Added box when you are pressing the mouse);
3. Click Start again to reset all variables;
4. Than click again on a div : WHY there are two Added div? I've removed the previous one with `$('#boxTemp').remove();`

Can you help me to resolve this trouble? If I remove `BoxImmagineFutura.insertBefore("#example2");` there isn't "clonation" of that div.

## FIRST EDIT :

Yeah, every time I call InitDragDrop() I should also unbind `mousedown()`, but this doesn't explain my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull your `var BoxImmagineFutura = null;` out of your function. Also, you don't need `BoxImmagineFutura.appendTo($("#container"));` as your `insertBefore` handles inserting it into the DOM.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pfnw9/3/)**

Comment: Ok for the appendTo. But Why pulling `var BoxImmagineFutura = null;` works. It doesnt make sense...

Comment: Oh well, Now I understand why! Calling two times mousedown() doing an insertBefore of two different references! Thank you ;)

Comment: Yes you're re-binding the mousedown event every time you init your function. Another possible solution would be to change your function to `$('.example').one('mousedown',function(e) {
        BoxImmagineFutura.insertBefore("#example2");
        BoxImmagineFutura.show();
    });` which allows you to keep the `var BoxImmagineFutura = null;` within the function as you originally had it. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pfnw9/6/

Answer (score 0):

You are just hiding BoxImmagineFutura on mouseover not removing. 
if you see carefully, $('#boxTemp').remove(); will be called only once when you click on Start. And at first instance '#boxTemp' doesn't exist so $('#boxTemp').remove(); will do nothing. Next, when you mousedown on ".example" it will simple insert another div before "#example2" and when you "mouseup" you are simply hiding this div.

Instead of that if you simply move $('#boxTemp').remove(); in "mouseup" event, your problem will be solved.

Also you are not doing anything for cloning. that means, once you used BoxImmagineFutura, it's gone.

Comment: When I click "start" it will be removed.... so if I call start two time (the first, which is not exist) and the second(removing the one added at the first time) it will be ok the position...